# FlowRouter force ignore global trigger

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I have a FlowRouter trigger set up like this:

```
FlowRouter.triggers.enter([function(context,redirect){
  if(!Meteor.userId()) {
    FlowRouter.go('home');
  }
}]);
```

This redirects the users to the homepage if they're not logged in. What I'd like to do is set up another route like so:

```
FlowRouter.route('/:name', {
  name: 'menu',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('MenuLayout');
  }
});
```

What I'd like to do is allow the user to visit a `/:name` route even if they're not logged in, but obviously the global trigger prevents me from doing that, as it just redirects me to the homepage if I try to visit a `/:name` route while logged out.

Is there any way I can allow this specific route to ignore the global trigger?

Comment: can you post your full script route.js ?

Comment: @John I managed to get around it by triggering the redirect inside the route, instead of setting a global trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the issue:

```
FlowRouter.triggers.exit([trackRouteExit], {except: ["home"]});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around it by triggering the redirect inside the route, instead of setting a global trigger.

If anyone has any other methods, I'd gladly see them.